# Is This Possible in a Browser? [JavaScript / HTML]

Tags: javascript

I have Javascript code that opens ISBNs of books on Amazon using hyperlinks (feel free to try, for example: 0133098648). I would like the URL to open up on a new window with all links clicked in a new tab on that same window. It appears one can only open in a new tab of the current window, or a new window every time.

Is what I am looking to do even possible? I've been reading that something like this is restricted by browsers for security reasons; Maybe there's a work around? I've been pulling my hair out trying to find a solution for this, if I could it would make my life much more easier.

A picture to describe my question: http://imgur.com/a/5lUP4

Please use JSfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/mq1efed2 ( Code does not work on Stackoveflow)

```html
<html>
<div><b>ISBN Hyperlinker</b></div>
<textarea id=numbers placeholder="paste isbn numbers as csv here" style="width:100%" rows="8" >

</textarea>
<div><b>Hyperlinked text:</b></div>
<div id="output" style="white-space: pre"></div>
<script>
//the input box.
var input = document.getElementById('numbers');
var output = document.getElementById('output')
var base = 
    'https://www.amazon.ca/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords='

//adding an event listener for change on the input box
input.addEventListener('input', handler, false);

//function that runs when the change event is emitted
function handler () {
  var items = input.value.split(/\b((?:\d\s*?){10,13})\b/gm);
  // Build DOM for output
  var container = document.createElement('span');
  items.map(function (item, index) {
    if (index % 2) { // it is the part that matches the split regex:
      var link = document.createElement('a');
      link.textContent = item.trim();
      link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
      link.setAttribute('href', base + item.replace(/\D+/g, ''));
      container.appendChild(link);
    } else { // it is the text next to the matches
      container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item))
    }
  });
  // Replace output
  output.innerHTML = '';
  output.appendChild(container);
}
handler(); // run on load


</script>
</html>
```

Comment: If some restriction exists "for security reasons", there is no "workaround".

Comment: did you ask this exact question earlier?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are asking. If you add an onclick handler to the link and that onclick handler uses window.open without 3rd parameters, it should open in a tab, with a height and width or other 3rd parameters, it should popup a window. target="...." will open in a tab in most browsers. If the content is not from same origin, you will not be able to manipulate the new windows/tabs after opening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this isn't possible.  Web pages cannot dictate whether or not content opens up in tabs or new windows.  It's up to the user/browser to decide.

At best, you can open a new window with `window.open()`, but that doesn't give you control over tabs in a specific window later.

Comment: Ah, thats a shame. Ill have to look to other technologies or methods to extract my information in a efficient manner.

Comment: @Albert Maybe consider frames?  Haven't seen that in awhile, but it should still work, provided the sites you link to don't bust out of frames.

Comment: Very smart idea, I think this could work with me. Only issue is it appears Amazon.ca blocks the iframe request, although other domains work such as w3schools.com ... Any workarounds?

Comment: @Albert What specifically does your web app do?  Trying to think of workflow and other UI possibilities.

Comment: If theres another way I can contact you I can get in to more detail but basically its as follows:

Comment: If theres another way I can contact you I can get in to more detail but this whole process is for researching and apprasing books listed on Amazon and its as follows: I will receive a list of ~1-30 ISBN's which I will paste in to the web app's search box (this will generate links to Amazon for every ISBN allowing me to quickly open up each one in a new tab ) I then proceed to check each tab to evaluate every book based on the books information and I will copy / paste the book title on to a email document and type prices / notes next to each title.

Comment: The process I am trying to solve now is the first step of my ultimate goal. What I would like to do is have my screen split in half, the web app on the left and all windows + tabs I open via ISBN hyperlink on the right allowing me to quickly decipher information from each tab while also having the web app display an extra <textarea> section where it scrapes book titles and other potential information on the page so I dont have to and all I have to do is write comments / prices next to these pregenerated titles on the web app <textarea> section.

Comment: I hope this makes sense lol. There are more complicated features I want implemented which Is when I will seek to hire a programmer, but I need to know if the foundations will work beforehand as my original question.

Comment: @Albert Ah, so you're stealing pricing information from Amazon?  If this is legit, why not just contact Amazon for API access?  In any case, if you're going to steal the info, consider scraping server-side and get the data you need more efficiently.  (You might get blocked eventually, but I suspect it will be easier than doing what you're doing now.)  Take a look at PhantomJS.

Comment: API access is something I already have, there are plugins and unique information I must see for each ISBN link on the product page I open that the API will not provide.

Comment: Thats why having each tab open on the right side of my screen in a separate window will be the most efficient with information already scraped in the backend